# Plotting graph of items in list into corresponding category using PyPlot in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a list with **10 records**, and each record has **one or more elements** with **3 categories** like below:

```
list = [('0.4', 2, 'doc4.txt'),('0.04', 13, 'doc4.txt'), ('0.5', 4, 'doc4.txt')]
       [('0.5', 6, 'doc3.txt'),('0.04', 13, 'doc3.txt'), ('0.5', 4, 'doc3.txt')]
       [('0.6', 8, 'doc2.txt')]
       [('0.4', 2, 'doc5.txt'), ('1.0', 7, 'doc5.txt')]
       [('0.2', 2, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.4', 2, 'doc6.txt'),('0.8', 2, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.34', 5, 'doc6.txt'),('0.76', 4, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.5', 3, 'doc6.txt')]
       [('0.3', 7, 'doc9.txt')]
       [('0.1', 8, 'doc12.txt')]
       [('0.3', 9, 'doc11.txt'),('1.0', 8, 'doc11.txt')]
       [('0.9', 7, 'doc22.txt')]
       [('0.3', 7, 'doc24.txt')]
```

You many notice **the third category** of every record has **the same text** for each record. There are **10 categories** as *the list* consists of **10 records**.
According to the structure of the list:

For example, `[('0.6', 8, 'doc2.txt')]`

1. First element, '0.6' represents X-axis value in the range of [0.1 -> 1.0]
2. Second element of an integer represents Y-axis value in graph
3. Third element, *'doc2.txt'* represents the Category name in graph

The list should be plotted as the image below,
[image]

I've been trying with several approaches, but still couldn't figure that out

```
>>> plt.scatter(*zip(*list))
>>> plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
>>> plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
>>> plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just keep the list as it is and iterate over it. You'd then produce a scatter plot for each sublist in the outer list, as the items from the sublist should share the same marker, color and legend label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#don't call a variable "list" or "print" or any other python command's name
liste=[[('0.4', 2, 'doc4.txt'),('0.04', 13, 'doc4.txt'), ('0.5', 4, 'doc4.txt')],
       [('0.5', 6, 'doc3.txt'),('0.04', 13, 'doc3.txt'), ('0.5', 4, 'doc3.txt')],
       [('0.6', 8, 'doc2.txt')],
       [('0.4', 2, 'doc5.txt'), ('1.0', 7, 'doc5.txt')],
       [('0.2', 2, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.4', 2, 'doc6.txt'),('0.8', 2, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.34', 5, 'doc6.txt'),('0.76', 4, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.5', 3, 'doc6.txt')],
       [('0.3', 7, 'doc9.txt')],
       [('0.1', 8, 'doc12.txt')],
       [('0.3', 9, 'doc11.txt'),('1.0', 8, 'doc11.txt')],
       [('0.9', 7, 'doc22.txt')],
       [('0.3', 7, 'doc24.txt')]]

markers=[ur"$\u25A1$", ur"$\u25A0$", ur"$\u25B2$", ur"$\u25E9$"]
colors= ["k", "crimson", "#112b77"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, l  in enumerate(liste):
    x,y,cat = zip(*l)
    ax.scatter(list(map(float, x)),y, s=64,c=colors[(i//4)%3],
                                      marker=markers[i%4], label=cat[0])

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01,1), borderaxespad=0)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues. You assignment of `list` makes no sense (presumably you forgot some parentheses). Also, you really shouldn't reuse built-in names like "list". You should not represent floats as strings (your x coordinates). You cannot simply unpack a list into `plt.scatter` and hope that magically all of these issues work themselves out.

Below some code how to properly pass your data to `scatter` (I use `plot` instead of `scatter` as you can pass `plot` proper colour names).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 'list' is a bad name for a variable as it overwrites the list() built-in function
# -> rename to data
data = [
    [('0.4', 2, 'doc4.txt'),('0.04', 13, 'doc4.txt'), ('0.5', 4, 'doc4.txt')],
    [('0.5', 6, 'doc3.txt'),('0.04', 13, 'doc3.txt'), ('0.5', 4, 'doc3.txt')],
    [('0.6', 8, 'doc2.txt')],
    [('0.4', 2, 'doc5.txt'), ('1.0', 7, 'doc5.txt')],
    [('0.2', 2, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.4', 2, 'doc6.txt'),('0.8', 2, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.34', 5, 'doc6.txt'),('0.76', 4, 'doc6.txt'), ('0.5', 3, 'doc6.txt')],
    [('0.3', 7, 'doc9.txt')],
    [('0.1', 8, 'doc12.txt')],
    [('0.3', 9, 'doc11.txt'),('1.0', 8, 'doc11.txt')],
    [('0.9', 7, 'doc22.txt')],
    [('0.3', 7, 'doc24.txt')]
]

# flatten nested list
flat = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]

# convert strings to numbers
numeric = [(float(x), y, label) for (x, y, label) in flat]

# create a dictionary that maps a label to a set of x,y coordinates
data = dict()
for (x, y, label) in numeric:
    if label in data:
        data[label].append((x,y))
    else:
        data[label] = [(x,y)]

# initialise figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'brown', 'violet', 'magenta', 'white', 'black']

# populate figure
for color, (label, xy) in zip(colors, data.iteritems()):
    x, y = np.array(xy).T
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', label=label, color=color)

ax.set_xlim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 16)
ax.legend(numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It was my reckless mistake to assign as 'list' to give proper name for my sample list, and appreciate for your quick response. You just saved the day.